# How can I populate the textbox of an HTML file input?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

This one has got me stumped.  I am currently rendering a form using ASP MVC, it has a bunch of fields, one of them is an `<input type="file"...`

The file upload works great, but when I return the form to the user, the textbox that contains the file is empty.  I would like to show the filepath in the textbox, but it appears the *value* field does not populate this textbox.

Ie. `<input type="file" value="abc.txt" />` does not put "abc.txt" into the textbox.

How can I populate the textbox of an HTML file input?  Is there another property that I should be using other than the value property?

Any help would be much appreciated,

Comment: I recommend staying away from `<input type="file" />`. Browsers made them very difficult to stylistically and functionally manipulate for security reasons. It gets ugly when you use CSS and JavaScript hacks to work around that.

Comment: Point taken Baddie, right now it's too late (and it's working fine), but I might revisit the code for better styling and behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That textbox is readonly and you can't explicitly set the value of it.

Comment: +1, and the reason it is readonly is because if you *could* set it, then you could set it to any file on the file system.  If the browser subsequently actually allowed that file to upload, you would have a gross security issue.

Comment: +1 for answering the question (as opposed to my mis-reading of it *cough* ), with thanks @Kirk

Comment: @Kirk - You are exactly right with the reason it is readonly.  Now you can use jQuery to clear the contents of that textbox, but anything else would definitely be a huge security issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I could indicate the file in free text beside the textbox, your explanation makes total sense.  It's too bad since I'm indicating a file that they have already uploaded, but the best security solution was to make the textbox read-only, no exceptions.